# What is the meaning of 认知?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

What exactly is the meaning of 认知 here? : 我奶奶说过：“人们应该在最美好的时候离开。”因为这个认知而获得诺贝尔奖的，不是我奶奶，而是心理学家丹尼尔•卡内曼。？？Detailed explanation please

提前感谢。

Answer (score 2):

Realisation or an epiphany may be closer to the original than familiarity, because it doesn’t take a deep understanding or a mastery of a concept to 认知 it.
eg.
他对市场的认知非常浅薄 his understanding of the market is very superficial
Note 认知 is not commonly used in day to day conversation as it rings a bit formal, academic

Answer (score 1):

认知： realize

我奶奶说过：
My granma once told me:
“人们应该在最美好的时候离开。
We should quit when the times are at their best.
因为这个认知而获得诺贝尔奖的，不是我奶奶，而是心理学家丹尼尔•卡内曼。
It wasn't my granma who was awarded a Nobel Prize for realizing this, it was the psychologist Daniel Kahneman.

Answer (score 0):

认知 - 對某種事物或某種觀念點的深入認識和了解 (the ability to recognize and understand something, or concept in depth, usually through one's knowledge, training, or experience.) For example:

- 基於對科學的認知他極力反對迷信 - Based on his familiarity (深入認識) and understanding (了解) of science, he forcefully against superstitious practices.
- 由於我對他的認知,我相信他 - Due to my familiarity with him and deep understanding of him, I trust him.

**Add - Translation**

"我奶奶说过：“人们应该在最美好的时候离开。”因为这个认知而获得诺贝尔奖的，不是我奶奶，而是心理学家丹尼尔•卡内曼."

- My grandma ever said: "People shall know to leave at the most glorious moment/time". Because **a deep understanding (comprehension) of the meaning** behind this saying and receiving the Nobel Award wasn't my grandma, but the psychologist Daniel Kahneman.

Comment: I'd rather use *comprehension* for 认知.

Comment: @iBug In agreement.